# ¿Cómo puedo aplanar una lista de listas y obtener una lista con todos los elementos de las sublistas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Quiero saber si hay alguna función implementada para quitar los corchetes en una lista y hacerla continua, por ejemplo:

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

Lo quiero pasar a

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Estoy usando Python 3.6.

Comment: Hola CZiffrak, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. **Si no lo has intentado**, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Con [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) puedes utilizar la expansión de elementos:

```
list(itertools.chain(*A))
```

Si no, utiliza una doble comprensión de listas:

```
[item for lista in A for item in lista]
```

Dado `A=[[1,2,3],[4,5]]` en ambos casos obtenemos `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: Hola fedorqui, gracias por responderme. La verdad trate de implementar esas 2 formas pero no pude, soy principiante en python, realmente no se que esta mal porque con itertools cargo el modulo y al aplicar la funcion me sale que itertools no esta definido. 

Y en lo de comprension de listas me tira: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @Cziffrak define "no pude"

Comment: from itertools import*
A=[1,1,1,1,3,2,4,4,4, [1,5]]
B=[]
B=list(itertools.chain(*A))

tengo eso y me dice NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined

Comment: @Cziffrak ¿te funciona `import itertools`?

Comment: Creo que no está funcionando. Me sale un warning en la linea donde cargo el modulo.
'from itertools import*' used; unable to detect undefined names. Estoy trabajando en pythonanywhere.com

Comment: @Cziffrak deberías dar más detalles. Si utilizas Python 3.6 esto debería ser inmediato, seguramente tienes un problema en tu instalación de Python.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en pythonanywhere.com, no creo que haya problemas con esa página

Comment: @Cziffrak probablemente aprenderías más y mejor si instalas Python en local y ejecutas los scripts en tu máquina.

Comment: Si, eso haré. Muchas gracias fedorqui,

Comment: me sirvio lo de la doble comprension de lista pero... podrias explicar que es lo que entiende o que es lo que hace python ahi? tambien soy principiante en este lenguaje

Answer (score 0):

Hola si lo quieres hacer sin ninguna dependencia puedes iterar cada lista por separado. Primero iteras la lista `A[0] que es  [1, 2, 3]`, luego `A[1] = [4,5]` y luego vas agregando cada elemento por separado a una nueva matriz "B".

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]

B = []

for lista1 in A:
    for numero in lista1:
        B.append(numero)

print(B) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Las soluciones usando itertools.chain o una doble lista por comprensión funcionan sólo en el caso preguntado, pero no funcionan en los siguientes casos:

```
a = [1, 2, [3, 4]]
a = [[[1, 2], [3, 4, [5]]]]
```

Una forma elegante de resolver esta situación y no tener restricciones en cuanto al nivel de anidación de la lista es usando una función recursiva de la siguiente forma:

```
def flatter(lst):
ret = []
for elem in lst:
    if isinstance(elem, list):
        ret.extend(flatter(elem))
    else:
        ret.append(elem)
return ret

>>> flatter([1, 2, [3, 4]])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> flatter([[[1, 2], [3, 4, [5]]]])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Como se puede ver en el ejemplo, se comprueba cada elemento si es una instancia de lista. Si es una lista se extiende la lista actual con lo que devuelva una llamada recursiva a la misma función, y si no es una lista, se añade a la lista actual.
También se podría comprobar si es un iterador para hacerlo más genérico pero quería que se entendiera bien el concepto.

En esta entrada muestro cada concepto de esta solución para profundizar más en el tema: [aplanar listas en Python](https://elpythonista.com/pyquiz-7)

Answer (score 0):

Como parece por las respuestas, *aplanar una lista* se puede hacer de muchas formas distintas. Aquí añado algunas más:

Una simple es usando la función `sum()`:

```py
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]

lista_aplanada = sum(A, start=[])
```

Básicamente, concatena las sublistas partiendo de la lista vacía `[]` y *sumando* cada una de las sublistas.

Cuando la estructura a aplanar fuera más compleja (sublistas anidadas a distintos niveles) es más recomendable crear un *iterador* que recorra en orden los elementos de las sublistas. Nos ahorraremos así la creación de una nueva lista:

```py
def flatten(lst):

    match lst:
        case []:
            return  # final del iterador

        case [head, *tail]:
            if isinstance(head, list):
                yield from flatten(head)
            else:
                yield head

            yield from flatten(tail)

for i in flatten(A):
    print(i)
```