# ¿Cómo podría pasar de estos ciclos for a una estructura más adecuada, por así decirlo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
data = json.load(f)
for list in data.values():
     for word in list:
        words.append(word)
```

Me gustaría que todo esto quedara con un formato similar al siguiente, para hacerlo en una sola línea de código. Por cierto, no recuerdo cómo se llama esta forma de construir listas.

```py
words = [word for word in ([list for list in data.values()])]
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que definas la función `flatten` que nos propone la documentación de Python en sus [fórmulas con itertools](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general, la *compresión de listas* es lo recomendable. En este caso lo que quieres hacer se conoce habitualmente como *"aplanar una lista"*, concatenar todas las listas para convertir una lista de listas en una lista plana.

Un truco para concatenar listas es usa la función `sum()`. Sin poner nada más, `sum()` se usa para sumar números; pero también es posible "sumar listas", o sea, concatenar listas, con tan solo añadir como elemento inicial una lista vacía `[]`:

```py
data = json.load(f)
words = sum(data.values(), start=[])
```

Normalmente, usar `sum()` es más eficiente que una compresión de listas, aunque no tan flexible.

Tienes más formas de aplanar listas en la pregunta: [¿Cómo puedo aplanar una lista de listas y obtener una lista con todos los elementos de las sublistas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167046/)

Answer (score 0):

Se llama comprensión de listas o [list comprehension](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+comprehension+loop).

Un problema que tienes en el código es que estás sobreescribiendo la función [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) de python. Recomiendo cambies el nombre de la variable `list` por otra cosa.

Entonces este código (algo refactorizado):

```py
words = []
for vlist in json.load(f).values():
     for word in vlist:
        words.append(word)
```

Reescrito en comprensión quedará:

```py
words = [word for vlist in json.load(f).values() for word in vlist]
```